# How do I suppress some Maven logs but keep other output?

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j

I'm running Maven in a CI environment and want to see some of its log output - but I don't want to see routine messages about downloading artifacts etc.

I can use `-q` but that suppresses everything useful too.

Maven uses slf4j and by default uses the slf4j-simple backend so there's no `logging.properties` etc, and anyway how would I even find out which class generates the log messages?

e.g. if I have

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] XXX JDBC Driver - JDBC 4.2                             [bundle]
[INFO] XXX JDBC Driver aggregate                                   [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< XXX:XXX >------------------
[INFO] Building XXX JDBC Driver - JDBC 4.2 XXXX           [1/2]
[INFO] -------------------------------[ bundle ]-------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ XXXX-jdbc ---
[INFO] Deleting XXXX/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ XXX-jdbc ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:parse-version (parse-version) @ XXXX-jdbc ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) @ XXXX-jdbc ---
[WARNING] Ignoring missing properties file: XXX/build.local.properties
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jcp:6.0.1:preprocess (preprocessSources) @ XXX-jdbc ---
[INFO] Added MAVEN property mvn.project.name=XXX JDBC Driver - JDBC 4.2
[INFO] Added MAVEN property mvn.project.version=XX.YY.ZZ
.... blah blah blah ...
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Running XXX.TestSuite
Tests run: 58, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 6.43 sec
```

and for this task I just want the test output, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Maven uses [slf4j-simple](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html). Its configuration is loaded from the classpath in a file [`simplelogger.properties`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/apache-maven/src/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties). You can modify the classpath to put your own copy of this file first, but you can also override these properties by setting system properties.

First re-run your build with `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true` so you can see which classes the logs are coming from. Then adjust log levels as desired by setting additional properties named `-Dorg.slf4.simpleLogger.log.[[classname]]=[[level]]`.

**You may require the `-B` (batch) flag too**.

I find it convenient to set these in a `.mvn/maven.config` file in my project, but you can use `MAVEN_OPTS` or the command line instead. An example [`.mvn/maven.config`](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) might be:

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.igormaznitsa.jcp.maven.PreprocessorMojo=warn
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger=warn
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering=warn
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo=warn
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true
```

Note that putting these options in a `simplelogging.properties` of the project *being compiled* will *not work*, it must be in the classpath of the *maven runtime*.

Also beware that `.mvn/maven.config` doesn't appear to support comments. I tried `#`, `;`, `//`, `/* .. */`.